# I can't navigate to another activity

Tags: android

[Android Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILT9p.png) I'm a real noob when it comes to Android Studio, and I'm trying to make it so when I click a button in IntroActivity, it will direct me to the FeaturedActivity page, which contains a list and navigation drawer, if that's important. But when I click the first time in the emulator, the app stops, and when I go back and click it again, nothing happens. I have Java Code for both activities. Could someone help me please?

```
<activity
android:name=".FeaturedActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_featured"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

The first activity

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button ComeInButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    ComeInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ComeIn);
    ComeInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, FeaturedActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Featured Activity

```
public class FeaturedActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

String [] art_Names;
TypedArray pics;
String[] artist_Names;
String[] desc;

List<RowItem> rowItems;
ListView myListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_featured);

    rowItems=new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    art_Names=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Featured_Arts);
    pics=getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.Art_Pics);
    artist_Names=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Artist_Names);
    desc=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Descriptions);

    for(int i=0;i<art_Names.length;i++){
        RowItem item=new RowItem(art_Names[i], pics.getResourceId(i, -1),artist_Names[i],desc[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    myListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomerAdapter adapter = new CustomerAdapter(this,rowItems);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    myListView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);





    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}





public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    String art_name=rowItems.get(position).GetArtName();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+art_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.featured, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you also add error log from logcat?

Comment: Click the "Android Monitor" tab on the bottom of your screen and trigger the error. Any message would appear there

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague on the details, but taking a shot in the dark, did you register FeaturedActivity in the app manifest?

Something like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".FeaturedActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_featured"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

should be in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

You are probably getting a nice error message in logcat, so please look there :)

Comment: No you don't put that in your java file, you put in your AndroidManifest.xml file in your project

Answer (score 0):

I think the crash cause is where you are casting `FeaturedActivity` to `View.OnClickListener` inside `FeatureActivity#onCreate()`. since it does not implement `View.OnClickListener`, you get `ClassCastException` and since you do not catch this exception, then your app crashes.

**EDIT** I meant this line:

```
public class FeaturedActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        ...     
        myListView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this); // this line
    }       
    ...
}
```

**EDIT 2** You can fix it by implementing `View.OnClickListener` in `FeatureActivity` like this:

```
public class FeaturedActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        ...     
        myListView.setOnClickListener(this); // cast is not needed anymore
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClick(View v) {
        // handle click
    }
    ...
}
```

By the way, If you want to handle item click for `ListView` you should use [AdapterView#setOnItemClickListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) instead so you get notified when one of the items in `ListView` is clicked

Comment: Do you mean this line in FeaturedActivity.java?         myListView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

Comment: How would I fix it?

Comment: I'm not doing anything with the onClick function. I have the onItemClick function. Is that pretty much the same thing here?

Comment: Well as far as i know, one of the ways to get notified of item clicks inside `ListView` is to setting `OnItemClickListener` for your `ListView`, not `OnClickListener`. And I can not find where you have set `OnItemClickListener` for `myListView` in your code so your `onItemClick` method does not call whenever an item is clicked! I suggest you do a search for how to detect item clicks in `ListView` if that is what you want to do. Also, you can find a tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html